# Pipe continuous stream to another command

Tags: awk, stream, pipe, tail

I wrote a program to analyze the log files in real time. I need to feed it with the IPs. It works fine with the command:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | ./my_program
```

Also, I can get the IPs in real time with the command:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $1}'
```

When I pipe it to my program, my program does not receive anything:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | ./my_program
```

It seems like a matter of buffering. Is there way of piping continuous stream to my program?

Comment: If buffering is done `awk` then you could make it line buffered. Can you try  `tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk -W interactive '{print $1}' | ./my_program` to see it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the ultimate solution to my buffering problem [here](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html).

> The problem is that stdio is being buffered, ...